# After flutter build web shows nothing on build files not working shows blank

Tags: flutter, build, flutter-web

on flutter run -d chrome run fines but on flutter build web after build I run build index.html from build/web/index.html shows nothing only blank screens and in console shows some errors, note this is flutter counter app.

[Consoles errors screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Jtfp.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to run it by some application server, See below example to run it on node server using [ExpressJs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express).

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const port = 3000

// add web folder path created after flutter build
app.use(express.static('your_web_folder_path'))

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Example app listening at http://localhost:${port}`)
})
```